# Stripe API PHP, getting all payment methods (do I need a customer ID every time?)

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Good day,

I have a question that got me stuck for the entire afternoon already.
Trying to make a Stripe wrapper class that handles all the action for me.

Downloaded the API class from https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php

**What I am trying to do**

I created a class that loads all files required for the API. Initiates the API object and therein I am creating all methods I would need to handle all of it.

- __construct() : initiates the API, sets API key etc
- payment_methods() : fetches all payment methods
- create_payment() : create payment, sets payment intend, retrieves it and confirms it
- payment_callback() : fetch the current payment state failed/succeeded/timeout something else

I have quite some experience with the Dutch Mollie API and in the past I have worked with Ogone/Ingenico and Multisafe Pay.

But out of all I like the Mollie API the most.

Several very simple calls that do all for you.

**Where I get stuck**

Now I wanted to create a class method that shows all payment methods available.

```
public function payment_methods(){
    ///######## ATTEMPT TO LOAD THE PAYMENT METHODS
    $methods = $this->obj->paymentMethods->all();
    exit(print_r($methods));
}
```

**The error I am getting**

> This generates me the following error : *( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught
> (Status 400) (Request req_N40Ykkerh8nRjQ) Missing required param:
> customer. thrown in
> K:\wamp64\www\stripe_api\stripe\lib\Exception\ApiErrorException.php on
> line 38*

Now I am trying to see what I have been overlooking however what I can find is :

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
);
$stripe->paymentMethods->all([
  'customer' => 'cus_AJ6bY3VqcaLAEs',
  'type' => 'card',
]);
```

Now this obviously shows a customer ID : *cus_AJ6bY3VqcaLAEs*
So one would say I would always have a customer ID.
But now how to obtain one?

I see in my stripe account I can create a Customer. But when one would like to load a payment screen displaying all available payment methods you ain't gonna tell that I have to create a new customer for each page load? Since in a single page payment and order screen you simply ain't gonna do that.

What am I overlooking? Since the manual is imho a tad too bloated and shows me a lot of irrelevant data unfortunately.

**Edit**

---

What I wanted indeed is a list of all supported payments.

Since I could find a list with all supported payments on their manual page :
https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

- alipay
- au_becs_debit
- bacs_debit
- bancontact
- card
- eps
- fpx
- giropay
- ideal
- oxxo
- p24
- sepa_debit
- sofort

But I thought these where examples. Since whenever I use them to create a payment method I get an error :

**#1**

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request
> req_DCdOl1aqiw9qSF) No such PaymentMethod: 'card'

**#2**

> mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught (Status 400) (Request
> req_8juJf73eAGYGaS) No such PaymentMethod: 'ideal'

It doesn't matter which one I choose. I always get the same error.
Quite certain I am doing something wrong. But what?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean when you say that you want to display all the payment methods?  What exactly are you wanting to show? A list such as "VISA, Mastercard, Amex..." ?  Or ????

Comment: I would like all payment methods available. So AliPay, Visa, Amex, iDeal etc etc. Or isn't this possible?

Comment: It looks like that's a type you would supply:  https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/create

Comment: You could try getting all customers then getting payment methods for each customer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the documentation (although compared to SagePays I would say the more the better) [I just wish there were more thorough examples]

From what I understand, Payment Methods are those methods attached to a customer.

To create a customer, either use the Web Dashboard or use code:

```
require 'autoload.php'; // requires :: composer require stripe/stripe-php
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient($stripe_secretkey);

$customerId = "";
$json = $stripe->customers->search(['query' => 'name:\'' . $customerNm. '\'']);

foreach ($json->data as $key) {
     //echo "<LI>id:" . $key->id . ", email:" . $key->email . "<br>";
     if (strcmp($key->name, $customerNm) == 0) {
        $customerId = $key->id;
        $email = $key->email;
        break;
     }
}

// if customer does not exist - create it
if (strcmp($customerId, "") == 0) {

     //echo "<LI>Creating [$customerNm] / [$customerId] / [$email]";
     $json = $stripe->customers->create([
          'email' => $email,
          'name'  => $customerNm,
     ]);
     //echo "<LI><PRE>" . print_r($json, true) . "</PRE>";
    $customerId = $json->id;
 }
```

... to create a payment intent - you will need to use some front end `<script src='https://js.stripe.com/v3/'></script>` with some `$stripe->setupIntents->create(....)` usage.

Answer (score 1):

> But when one would like to load a payment screen displaying all available payment methods

and

> I would like all payment methods available. So AliPay, Visa, Amex, iDeal etc etc. Or isn't this possible?

It looks like you're looking for an API endpoint to find out all the different payment methods your account supports? Is that right? Or are you looking for something else? If so, that isn't supported at the moment.

To clarify, the PaymentMethod list() call you're making is meant to request "fetch me all the attached payment instruments on a particular Customer", hence the requirement of a Customer ID.

Comment: Thanks. Well I meant that but not entirely. I have to reroute my question I see

Comment: can you clarify instead, what your original question is then? I don't think that was clear

Comment: I am trying to get the correct payment method for Stripe. The notation. Since those provided on the website are invalid for some reason.

Comment: sorry the question is still not very clear, what do you mean by "get the correct payment method for Stripe". There's no one correct payment method, it depends on the country, account, supported payment methods, etc. Could you clarify a bit more? What do you mean by "notation"?